# Spam link under the Flash player in html website

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Code of the flash player:

```
<embed src="index.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="870" height="640" 
name="index" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

I have small website. I use adobe x-shockwave-flash pluginspage. Through this image are 10 image continue slide. But I don't understand why two extra link or spam link add under that player. It indicated in the image that need to remove.But how do it not understanding try to google but not satisfactory information to remove those spam link.
I also want to change the date.

When I want to write my website link in Facebook there some extra description adding. How can I remove this?

[image: http://hituner.com/Demo/image/Capture2.JPG]

Comment: Could you post a link to a live example?

Comment: rwphoto.org see the live preview and tell me details if possible....i am afraid –

Answer (score 1):

Without a live link it is harder to say but probably comes from a hack in your site and og data has been added.

Check the code on your site as it loads live by viewing the Page Source to see if there is og data in there that reflects the spam you are seeing.

Comment: http://www.rwphoto.org/  see the preview and tell me details if possible....i am afraid

Comment: What do you use to produce your site? A hosting service for photographers? Where did you get the plugin?